# Having problems injecting dependencies in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am a newbie in angularjs. My intention is to add this angularjs directive https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker to my app.js so that I can be able to select dates in one of my views buses.html. 
My app.js file looks something like this:

```js
My app.js file looks like this...
var busRest1 = angular.module("busReservator1", ["720kb.datepicker"]);
//dependency injection that fails
var busRest = angular.module("busReservator", ["ionic", "busRest1"]);
busRest.run(function($ionicPlatform, $state) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if(window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
    document.addEventListener("resume", function() {
        $state.go("home", {}, {location: "replace"});
    }, false);
});

busRest.factory('myService', function(){
    var savedData = {}
    function set(data){
        savedData = data;
    }
    function get(){
        return  savedData;
    }
    return {
        set: set,
        get: get
    }
});
busRest.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state("home", {
            url: "/home",
            templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
            controller: "homeCtrl",
        })
        
        .state("busList", {
            url: "/busList",
            templateUrl: "templates/busList.html",
            controller: "busListCtrl",
            cache: false
        })
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
});
busRest.controller("homeCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
    
}]);
busRest.controller('busListCtrl', ['$scope', 'myService2', function($scope, myService2) {
    //declaring an array of transporters
    $scope.transporters = [];
    $scope.AddTransporter = function(){
        transporters = [document.getElementById('transporter_agency').value, document.getElementById('transporter_vehicleType').value, document.getElementById('transporter_vehicleCapacity').value, document.getElementById('transporter_btnValue').value];
        myService2.set(transporters);
    };
}]);
busRest.controller('DataCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

  $http.get('js/datafile2.json').success(function (data) {

    $scope.artists = data.artists;
    $scope.albums = data.albums;
  })
}]);
```

```html
My index.html looks like this
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title>Bus Ticket Reservation</title>
        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- For the date picker css-->
        <link href="src/css/angular-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- For the date picker js -->
        <script src="src/js/angular-datepicker.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/forge.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/firebase.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angularfire.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="busReservator">
        <ion-pane>
            <ion-nav-bar class="bar-royal"></ion-nav-bar>
            <ion-nav-view ></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-pane>
    </body>
</html>
When I save and run, the app breaks and the browser window is emptied
```

Comment: injection is based on the string name, not the variable name.  use `busReservator1`, not `busRest1`.

Comment: also, why create a new module just to import `720kb.datepicker`? why not just add `720kb.datepicker` to the existing dependency list?

Comment: i tried it like you suggested and it didn't work and so i decided to try the other alternative of having two modules. Unfortunately I used variable name instead of string name in the injection. I have tried doing it with the string name and the app still breaks